# Insert into Access from SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, ms-access

I'm looking to copy a few thousand records from SQL Server into Access in C#. The other direction works using `SqlBulkCopy`. Is there anything in place to do this in reverse?

I'm trying my best to stay away from looping through each field in each record and building a heinous `Insert` statement that not only would take forever to run, but would likely crash horribly if anything changes.

Comment: I should've specified, I'm using a SqlConnection to connect to SQL Server and an OleConnection to connect to Access -- I'm doing a lot of other manipulation in my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will run against the MS Access OleConnection connection:

```
SELECT fld1, fld2 INTO accessTable FROM [sql connection string].sqltable
```

For example:

```
SELECT * INTO newtable 
FROM 
[ODBC;Description=Test;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=server\SQLEXPRESS;UID=uid;Trusted_Connection=Yes;DATABASE=Test].table_1
```

Or to append

```
INSERT INTO newtable
SELECT *
FROM [ODBC;Description=Test;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=server\SQLEXPRESS;UID=uid;Trusted_Connection=Yes;DATABASE=Test].table_1;
```

Or with FileDSN

```
INSERT INTO newtable
SELECT * 
FROM [ODBC;FileDSN=z:\docs\test.dsn].table_1;
```

You will need to find the right driver to suit, for example

```
ODBC;Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase; Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
```

From http://connectionstrings.com works for me, but check out your client version.

Comment: Looks like this is the right track, but I need some additional help with supplying a password instead of a trusted connection: `SELECT * FROM 
[ODBC;Description=Test;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=IpAddress;UID=Username;PASSWORD=Pass;DATABASE=DB].dbo.Orders` -- Am I entering the credentials wrong? They don't seem to work like this. Thank you kindly!

Comment: You will need to find the right driver to suit, for example `ODBC;Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;
Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;` from http://connectionstrings.com works for me, check out your client version.

Comment: You can also use DSN or FileDSN.

Comment: The string you just posted, `ODBC;Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase; Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;`, works to connect - so thank you! Now, for some reason, when I do a `SELECT` to test it, it returns all #DELETED rows in Access.. Is this normal?

Comment: No, it is not. When I run eg `SELECT * 
FROM [ODBC;FileDSN=z:\docs\test.dsn].table_1` I get records.

Comment: Strangely enough, if I do a `SELECT * INTO` it works as it should. Not sure why the `SELECT` was returning `#DELETED` rows, but meh.. I'm okay with not knowing for now. Thank you! :)

Comment: You might like to see http://dbaspot.com/sqlserver-odbc/246794-sql-2005-linked-table-ms-access-returns-deleted.html. You are welcome :)